# 400 (Bad Request) when requesting GA API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I got a `400 Bad Request` when trying to access Google Auth. I am using the demo code in this article:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

The address I am requesting is:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=875938******.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fanalytics.readonly&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay452650337&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&response_type=token&state=895891795%7C0.1215960807&authuser=0`

I have successfully created my own ClientId and Keys.

Is there anything I need to take care of?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your request.  First the scope, second the respons_type.  I'm not sure where on the page you linked that you found that example.   You should really try and find a library for what ever language you are using it will make it easer.  But if you want to know the exact URLs you should be posting they should look something like this.

---

The initial URI to request that the user give you access to there account should look like this In this case the scope notice my scope is different then yours and I'm requesting a code:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

Once they say yes you take the authentication Code you got from the above request and Post it back to request an access_token and a refresh_token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

this is the response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The accesstoken you get from the above request is what you will be using to make requests to the service.  After one hour your access token will have expired you will need to request a new access token you take the refreshtoken that you got above and post it to :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

This is the response:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't change anything in the original demo code except replacing my own ClientId and Key. And sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. It's quite confusing.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaScript and I tried both Browser Key and Server Key. Both are the same.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication  I think that's the example I used for JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I am using that one. I am just very confused that sometimes it would go 400 Bad Request. And I am not requesting much at all. I just manually refresh the page and sometimes it doesn't work...