# How to key for Google Analytics management API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the solution provided by @[DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)

[400 (Bad Request) when requesting GA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032474/400-bad-request-when-requesting-ga-api)

I can get data from the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

However, the token doesn't work for the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/)

Can someone please tell me how if they tokens should be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

instead of using ?key={YOUR KEY} , use ?access_token={access_token}

Don't know why they would say key rather than access_token