# tgoogleanalytics stops working in talend

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, talend

I am using the tgoogleanalytics version 6.1 in Talend 6.3. I fill in the details in the component. I also give the location of the client_secret.json
However, I get the following error and it gets stuck until I kill it manually:

```
Starting job counts at 15:28 03/02/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3719
[statistics] connected
2017-02-03 15:28:53.497:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2017-02-03 15:28:53.498:INFO::jetty-6.1.x
2017-02-03 15:28:53.512:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:39096
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=174006231113-mpd4dqr61uhm6rlvbhdma8o0791mv8g5.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:39096/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly
```

Comment: The log does not contain any error, you need just to open the given address in your browser

Comment: could be an authentication issue based on the OAuth message.

Comment: @54l3d The url throws a 400 error

Comment: @EchchamaNayak so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032474/400-bad-request-when-requesting-ga-api) may be helpful